# Mouse scroll only working after manually reload kernel module with Apple Magic Mouse 2

Tags: 20.04, kernel, mouse, mouse-scroll, magic-mouse

I am runing Ubuntu 20.04, and in order to make mouse scroll work with Apple Magic Mouse 2 which it's connected by bluetooth I need to manually unload and reload the mouse kernel modules by executing these lines every time I log into my account:

```
sudo rmmod hid_magicmouse  
sudo modprobe hid-magicmouse scroll-speed=1 scroll-acceleration=10
```

Is there any way to get it loaded correctly without doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to install the driver first?

```bsh
   sudo apt-get install dkms
    git clone https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver.git
    cd Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver/scripts
    chmod u+x install.sh
    sudo ./install.sh
```